How to use a Raspberry Pi to discharge a high voltage capacitor
I'm trying to use a piezo element as a tactile feedback actuator. I've successfully managed to use it with 10 * 9V batteries in series which had an output of 90 volts. However, I'd like to test it in a more controllable environment. I would like to use my Raspberry Pi Zero W 2 to output 100V (or more) in the piezo. I was thinking of charging a capacitor (probably via a motor driver) then allow the capacitor to discharge in the connected piezo. I have no idea how to control the discharge of a capacitor though and I also have no idea  if I need to have another element after the piezo to control its own energy output since piezos can act as capacitors themselves. Thanks for your help!

Could you possibly be more specific wrt exactly what it is you are trying to do?

what about a bleeder resistor(appropriate wattage of course) connected to the piezo?

There are dedicated high voltage Piezo drivers. E.g. the TI Piezo drivers products has some shown with a Vout (max) of 100 V or 200 V.
The Application Note DRV8662, DRV2700, DRV2665, and DRV2667 Configuration Guide shows the driver directly connected to the Piezo Actuator. E.g.:

Rather than answering the following part of the question body, it is a suggestion to look at drivers designed for high voltage Piezo Actuators:

I have no idea how to control the discharge of a capacitor though and I also have no idea if I need to have another element after the piezo to control its own energy output since piezos can act as capacitors themselves.

